# How can I use wget to download large files?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, wget

I want to get the ISO for a particular version of Linux, say 'Mint 14 “Nadia” KDE '. I tried using `wget` in the terminal to download the ISO of this distro:

```
$ wget http://mirror.ufs.ac.za/linuxmint/stable/14/linuxmint-14-kde-dvd-64bit.iso
```

or more generically:

```
$ wget http://server.com/path/to/some/largefile
```

After downloading to the point where it was ~30% (after like 2 hours), I was disappointed to see that it stopped downloading. I used `wget` because I didn't want to leave my browser on for the entire duration of the download.

In general is there some method where I can get `wget` to be able to resume if it fails to download a complete file?

Do I need to do something different when using `wget`?

Comment: [Don't crosspost](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). You end up getting duplicate answers, like you [already have](http://superuser.com/questions/611922/how-can-i-use-wget-to-download-large-files). Closing here

Comment: @MichaelMrozek - does this seem better? I've tried to clean up this question so it's more generic. LMK.

Comment: @slm The problem isn't that it's too specific, it's that it's posted on two sites, so the answers get forked. Sometimes we migrate and merge, but since your answer here is already on the SU one, I just closed it instead

Comment: @MichaelMrozek - so what can we do to resolve it? Just leave it alone now?

Comment: @slm Yes, it's resolved by closing it :)

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `--continue` options to `wget`.

```
$ wget --continue http://mirror.ufs.ac.za/linuxmint/stable/14/linuxmint-14-kde-dvd-64bit.iso
```

If it's able to it should resume the download. Also you might want to consider using `curl` or even a `bitorrent` client instead. You're able to resume much more easily with `bitorrent` vs. some of the other methods of downloading, and most of the Linux Distros are setup so that they can be downloaded using a `bittorrent` client such as `rtorrent`.

#### References

- [wget man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html)
- [curl man page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)
- [rtorrent user's guide](http://libtorrent.rakshasa.no/wiki/RTorrentUserGuide)

Comment: 'wget -c https://some.server/somewhere' also works